# req.body return a Object in json property name

Tags: javascript, json, express

I am making a form with js but req.body returns the following and I can't access the data

```
{ 'object Object': '' }

//with JSON.stringify:
{ '{"A":"a","B":"b","C":"c"}': '' }
```

Client

```
    var body = `{
        "A": "a",
        "B": "B",
        "C": "c"
    }`
    body = JSON.parse(body) // Object { A: "a", B: "b", C: "C" }
    body = JSON.stringify(body) // "{\"A\":\"a\",\"B\":\"b\",\"C\":\"c\"}"
const opts = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
},
body
}
console.log(body)
    fetch(`${document.URL}/post`, opts).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.json());

    })
})
```

server

```
router.post("/post", auth, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.status(201)
    res.end()
});
```

I would like to know how to go from this

```
{ '{"A":"a","B":"b","C": "c"}': '' }
```

to this

```
{ A: "a", B:"b", C: "c"}
```

**Solution**

thanks Barmar and Phil your answers solved it

replace `"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to `"Content-type": "application/json",` in headers
add `app.use(express.json())` in server.js

Comment: If you're sending a JSON body, you should use `Content-type: application/json`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Basic rule of thumb when creating JSON is **never manually create JSON**. Always use `JSON.stringify()` to serialise JS data structures. For example `const body = JSON.stringify({ A: "a", B: "b", C: "c" })`

Comment: Have you registered JSON body parsing middleware? Eg `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Content-type: application/json returns an empty json, why?

never manually create JSON: 
I'll keep it in mind, but it still returns the same

Comment: **Barmar** and **Phil** thanks for the solutions, they worked

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
const obj = { '{"A":"a","B":"b","C": "c"}': '' };
const arr = Object.keys(obj);

console.log(JSON.parse(arr[0]));
```

Comment: Well It Works But this is just wrong